# I can't able to type a Textinput, keyboard hided within 2 sec in android mobile using react native

Tags: react-native

I am a beginner at React Native. When I try to type a text in a Text Input box, I'm not able to type, because the keyboard hides within 2 seconds. I don't know why this happens, here is my code, kindly solve this issue, this issue only occurs on Android devices.

Here is my code,

```
 render() {
    return (
       <View style={styles.container1}>      
      <ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.container}>        
         <View style={styles.SectionStyle}>       
                <Image source={require('../assets/padlock.png')} style={styles.ImageStyle} />       
                 <TextInput
                    style={{flex:1}}
                    placeholder="Current Password"
                    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                    secureTextEntry
                    selectionColor={'#002B60'}
                    returnKeyType={'next'}
                    blurOnSubmit={false}
                    onSubmitEditing={() => this.passwordRef.focus()}
                    onChangeText={(oldpassword) => this.setState({oldpassword})}
                />       
              </View> </View>                               

       </View>
       </ScrollView>
       </View>

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Will my keyboard disappear when I try to enter text?

Comment: Yes, When i try to enter textinput automatically hide 2 seconds but ios working fine get issues from android only, Using for stack navigator this.props.navigation.navigate(loginscreen)

Comment: I fixed this issue with(this.props.navigation.replace('loginscreen') now working fine